# Hibernate: mapping column substring to a field

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to know if it is possible to map a table column "substring" to a field, here is a sample. 
Initially -->
column named 'description' contains this string '123456789'
After mapping -->
java class field named 'descSummary' contains '123'.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes using a [Column Transformer](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#mapping-column-read-and-write).

Comment: thank you for your answear, it is clean ... didn't get it out when browsing hibernate reference doc.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use a Hibernate custom UserType.

A rough example (some methods from the interface are left out for readability):

```
package org.example;

public class SubstringUserType implements UserType {
    @Override
    public Class<String> returnedClass() {
        return String.class;
    }

    @Override
    public Object nullSafeGet(final ResultSet rs, final String[] names, final SessionImplementor    session, final Object owner) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
        if (rs != null || names.length != 0 || null != names[0]) {
            String desc = rs.getString(names[0]);
            return desc.substring(0, 3);
        }
    }
}
```

and use the following annotation on the field.

```
@Type(type = "org.example.SubstringUserType")
```